# Combine multiple similar queries into one

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I need to calculate a weighted average using the following table. I have to calculate this number for `metric_1` up to `metric_10`. All the metric columns have a value from 1 to 5.

```
------------------------------------------------------
id | var      | weight | metric_1 | metric_2 | week
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 9        | 0.56   | 4        | 2        | 8
2  | 3        | 1      | 3        | 1        | 7
3  | 7        | 0.98   | 3        | 5        | 8
------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the query I'm using. I need same query for each metric, from 1 to 10.

```
SELECT
    weight, sample_size, detractor,
    (promoter * 100) / weight AS promoter_p,
    (promoter - detractor) * 100 / weight AS score
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(surveys.id) AS sample_size,
            SUM(weight),
            SUM(CASE WHEN var BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN pond END) AS promoter,
            SUM(CASE WHEN var BETWEEN 0 AND 6  THEN pond END) AS detractor,
            MAX(week)
        FROM surveys
        WHERE (var BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (metric_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
    ) t
```

I there a way to combine those queries instead of having one query for each metric? The only difference is the WHERE clause:

```
        WHERE (...) AND (metric_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5) /* metric_2, ...10 */
```

Comment: Which version of Postgres?

Comment: @ypercube I'm using 9.4

Comment: If that's correct: `All the metric columns have a value from 1 to 5.`, then you don't have a problem, because *all* results are the same. Please clarify: how selective are the predicates `metric_n BETWEEN 1 AND 5`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, each metric column can only have a value in the range of 1 to 5. But I don't understand how that changes anything?

Comment: The predicate `metric_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5` is `TRUE` for every row and therefore irrelevant. The result is the same for every `metric_n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metric columns are redundant in survey table. we can create a new metric type column to differentiate multiple metrics and to normalize survey table. we can even do this normalization in inline view.

following sample query may explain this. it use SurveyNormalized inline view and it take aggregate group by metricType.

```
CREATE TABLE #Surveys(id int, VAR int, [weight] float, metric_1 int, metric_2 int, [week] int)

INSERT INTO #Surveys VALUES(1, 9, 0.56 , 4, 2, 8), (2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 7), (3, 7, 0.98 , 3, 5, 8)

SELECT
    weight, sample_size, detractor,
    (promoter * 100) / weight AS promoter_p,
    (promoter - detractor) * 100 / weight AS score,
    t.metricType
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(id) AS sample_size,
            SUM(weight) [weight],
            SUM(CASE WHEN var BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 1 END) AS promoter,
            SUM(CASE WHEN var BETWEEN 0 AND 6  THEN 2 END) AS detractor,
            MAX(week) wk,
            metricType
        FROM (
                SELECT id, var, weight, metric_1 AS metric, 'metric_1' AS metricType, week
                FROM #Surveys
                WHERE (var BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (metric_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
                UNION
                SELECT id, var, weight, metric_2 AS metric, 'metric_2' AS metricType, week
                FROM #Surveys
                WHERE (var BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (metric_2 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
            )SurveyNormalised
            GROUP BY SurveyNormalised.metricType

    ) t
```

Comment: That's very cool. Thanks. But I don't understand something: The user can have a different response for each metric type. How do we account for that? So mertric_1 can be 4, and metric_2 can be 6, etc... I think I'm missing something...

Comment: do you mean where clause in inline SurveyNormalised view?

Comment: Ahh, never mind! I understand now. Thanks. Wouldn't it be more efficient to move the `WHERE (var BETWEEN 0 AND 10)` outside of the select clauses, just below the `GROUP BY`, since it's applicable to the entire query?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this:

```
WITH cte AS 
  ( SELECT 
        q.query_id,
        COUNT(d.id) AS sample_size,
        SUM(d.weight) AS weight,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.var BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN d.pond END) AS promoter,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.var BETWEEN 0 AND 6  THEN d.pond END) AS detractor,
        MAX(d.week) AS max_week
    FROM
        generate_series(1, 3)      -- change 3 to the number of different queries
          AS q (query_id) 
      CROSS JOIN
        surveys AS s
      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
        ( SELECT 1, s.*
          WHERE (metric_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)  --- query 1
        UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, s.*
          WHERE (metric_2 BETWEEN 3 AND 7)  --- query 2
        UNION ALL
          SELECT 3, s.*
          WHERE (metric_3 BETWEEN 6 AND 9)  --- query 3
        --- etc
        ) 
          AS d (query_id, id, var, weight, metric_1, metric_2, week) 
        ON d.query_id = q.query_id
    WHERE 
        (s.var BETWEEN 0 AND 10)
    GROUP BY
        q.query_id
    ) 
SELECT
    query_id,
    weight, sample_size, detractor, max_week,
    (promoter * 100) / weight AS promoter_p,
    (promoter - detractor) * 100 / weight AS score
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    query_id ;
```